# Why is the numerical solution coming same as analytical solution in C language?

Tags: c, floating-point, numerical-methods

I have coded a 1 dimension cfd problem but my numerical solution is coming same as to the analytical solution (up to 6 decimal places).

I am using TDMA method for numerical solution and for the analytical solution I am directly substituting the x value in the function T(x).

Analytical solution T(x) comes out to be `T(x) = -(x^2)/2 +11/21(x);`

E. g. 4 grid points then ;

```
  x0  = 0.000000,    x1  = 0.333333 ,   x2  = 0.666666 ,   x3  = 0.999999 .
T(x0) = 0.000000 , T(x1) = 0.119048 , T(x2) = 0.126984 , T(x3) = 0.023810.
```

And for numerical solution I have used TDMA technique, please refer the code below.

Enter n = 4 for the results.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void temp_matrix(int n, double *a, double *b, double *c, double *d, double *T);

int main() {
  int Bi = 20.0;
  int n;
  printf("%s ", "Enter the Number of total Grid Points");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  float t = (n - 1);
  double dx = 1.0 / t;
  int i;
  printf("\n");

  double q; // analytical solution below
  double z[n];
  for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
    q = (dx) * i;
    z[i] = -(q * q) / 2 + q * (11.0 / 21);
    printf("\nT analytical %lf ", z[i]);
  }

  double b[n - 1];
  b[n - 2] = -2.0 * Bi * dx - 2.0;
  for (i = 0; i <= n - 3; i++) {
    b[i] = -2.0;
  }

  double a[n - 1];
  a[n - 2] = 2.0;
  a[0] = 0;
  for (i = 1; i < n - 2; i++) {
    a[i] = 1.0;
  }

  double c[n - 1];
  for (i = 0; i <= n - 2; i++) {
    c[i] = 1.0;
  }

  double d[n - 1];
  for (i = 0; i <= n - 2; i++) {
    d[i] = -(dx * dx);
  }

  double T[n];
  temp_matrix(n, a, b, c, d, T);

  return 0;
}

void temp_matrix(int n, double *a, double *b, double *c, double *d, double *T) {
  int i;
  double beta[n - 1];
  double gama[n - 1];
  beta[0] = b[0];
  gama[0] = d[0] / beta[0];
  for (i = 1; i <= n - 2; i++) {
    beta[i] = b[i] - a[i] * (c[i - 1] / beta[i - 1]);
    gama[i] = (d[i] - a[i] * gama[i - 1]) / beta[i];
  }
  int loop;
  for (loop = 0; loop < n - 1; loop++)
    for (loop = 0; loop < n - 1; loop++)

      T[0] = 0;
  T[n - 1] = gama[n - 2];

  for (i = n - 2; i >= 1; i--) {
    T[i] = gama[i - 1] - (c[i - 1] * (T[i + 1])) / beta[i - 1];
  }
  printf("\n");
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("\nT numerical %lf", T[i]);

  }
}
```

Comment: 'but my numerical solution is coming same as to the analytical solution'..... so..... is that a problem?

Comment: Aside: `for(i=0;i<=n-1;i++)` is poor style for two reasons. `for(i=0;i<n;i++)` is idiomatic because it is more readable and less work for the brain, and if `n` is unsigned and `0` the ending condition will fail.

Comment: please properly format and indent your code. It's pretty unreadable now.

Comment: Why is it a *problem* that the numerical solution exactly matches the analytical solution up to any given precision?  Surely, one hopes to maximimize the precision to which one's numerical algorithms reproduce the exact analytical solution, yes?

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: And you do know, do you not, that in most C implementations, type `double` is good for about **16** decimal digits?  That's *ten orders of magnitude* more precision than you're looking at.

Comment: What happens to the truncation error ( with taylor series truncation ) and the round off error of the system ?

Comment: @chux yes, it's T(x3) thanks.

Comment: Anshuman Sinha, Is TDMA --> Tridiagonal matrix algorithm? What is cfd? (Computational fluid dynamics ?)

Comment: The exact results are because integrating `y''(x)=-1` with a second order method results in the exact quadratic solution polynomial. The errors are indeed just accumulated floating-point errors, they do not follow the order of the method.

Answer (score 6):

> Why is the numerical solution coming same as analytical solution in C language?

They differ, by about 3 bits.

Print with enough precision to see the difference.

Using the below, we see a a difference in the last hexdigit of the significand of x620 vs x619 of `T[3]`.  This is only 1 part in 10<sup>15</sup> difference.

```
#include<float.h>
printf("T analytical %.*e\t%a\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, z[i], z[i]);
printf("T numerical  %.*e\t%a\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, T[i], T[i]);
```

C allows `double` math to be performed at `long double` math when `FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 2` and then the same analytical/numerical results. Your results may differ from mine due to that as well as other subtle FP nuances.

```
printf("FLT_EVAL_METHOD %d\n", FLT_EVAL_METHOD);
```

Output

```
T analytical 0.0000000000000000e+00 0x0p+0
T analytical 1.1904761904761907e-01 0x1.e79e79e79e7ap-4
T analytical 1.2698412698412700e-01 0x1.0410410410411p-3
T analytical 2.3809523809523836e-02 0x1.861861861862p-6

T numerical  0.0000000000000000e+00 0x0p+0
T numerical  1.1904761904761904e-01 0x1.e79e79e79e79ep-4
T numerical  1.2698412698412698e-01 0x1.041041041041p-3
T numerical  2.3809523809523812e-02 0x1.8618618618619p-6

FLT_EVAL_METHOD 0
```

Comment: @Anshuman Sinha With printing more precision, how does your output compare?

Comment: your above code { printf("T analytical %.*e\t%a\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, z[i], z[i]); } . is not working in my programme . The following error shows up :

main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:26:43: error: ‘DBL_DECIMAL_DIG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         printf("T analytical %.*e\t%a\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, z[i], z[i]);

Comment: @AnshumanSinha Did you include `#include<float.h>`?  What C compiler/version are you using?  Is it C99 compliant?  (`DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` was introduced in C99) If you still have trouble, replace `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` with `17` or `(DBL_DIG + 3)`

Comment: yes I did include #include<float.h> . I am using an online compiler from the website onlinegdb.com.

Comment: It's running with 17. how to interpret the result ? 
T analytical 1.19047619047619041e-01    0x1.e79e79e79e79ep-4 , what's the meaning of 1.19047619047619041e-01 and 0x1.e79e79e79e79ep-4 together ?

Comment: @AnshumanSinha 1.19047619047619041e-01 is a _decimal_ textual representation of `z[1]`.  `0x1.e79e79e79e79ep-4` is a textual representation of `z[1]` showing a _hexadecimal_  significant `0x1.e79e79e79e79e` and a decimal  power of 2, `-4`.  It maps very close to the `double` bit patten that encodes `z[1]`.  This is useful for understanding how "different" two nearby `double` are - the key to the incorrect assertion "the numerical solution coming same".

Comment: @AnshumanSinha My "(DBL_DECIMAL_DIG was introduced in C99)" is incorrect.      `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` came out in C11 and onlinegdb.com version of C is C99. (`printf("%ld\n", __STDC_VERSION__)` reports `199901`.)  Use `17` for now.  Back to the 1st question: With printing more precision, how does your output compare?  For me with onlinegdb.com, your results are likely the same as posted in this answer.

Comment: The above comment is not getting deleted but my solution is only similar for last T values , but the other three are still coming same for both numerical and analytical upto the 17 decimal places.

Comment: other students are getting difference in analytical and numerical at the 4th decimal place only.

Comment: @AnshumanSinha  If the real question is why your results differ from the results of another program, it is useful to post both sources codes of both programs, their exact outputs, and the expected output - else too much guess work is involved.  To be fair, take time to answers [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52284303/why-is-the-numerical-solution-coming-same-as-analytical-solution-in-c-language/52284688?noredirect=1#comment91535803_52284303) before going further.